# imagettftext(): calculate font size to ensure text fits image width

Tags: php, imagettftext, dynamic-content, dynamic-image-generation

I'm using `imagettftext()` to write dynamic text on an image and I want it to fit my image width.

How can I calculate the font size by the text lenght?

Comment: You can't calculate the font size by the text length unless it's a monospace font. And there is no good approximation. A string of all W's will take up much more space than a string of all I's.

Answer (score 12):

You can calculate the bounding box of TTF text before outputting it with the `imagettfbbox` function. Unfortunately there is no direct way of scaling to fit a width, so you'll have to do it yourself.

One way of doing it is to pass the text with a default font size of, say 20, to `imagettfbbox` and retrieve the width from it. You can then calculate how much smaller or bigger the text should be to fit the size you want by calculating a scale factor:

```
scale = targetWidth / bboxWidth;
```

Then draw the text with the proper size:

```
fontSize = 20 * scale;
```

using the `imagettftext` function. Fonts don't scale 100% perfectly this way, but you'll get a very good approximation.

See the documentation of `imagettfbox` [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php).

Comment: To make the scale 100% perfect you could do a second pass with font 40 and calculate the scale based of the difference between 20 and 40 font size for the same input string.

Answer (score -2):

```
while (itsTooBigAccordingToimagettftext() && $fontSize > 0) {
    $fontSize--;
}
```

Comment: This will result in "Fatal error: Call to undefined function itsTooBigAccordingToimagettftext()". In other words, please give a better explanation of your answer instead of using semi-code :-)

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place where you're supposed to get guidance, not a fully working code. To me that's good guidance, the only error is it should read `itsTooBigAccordingToimagettfbbox()` and not `itsTooBigAccordingToimagettftext()` ;-)

Comment: Warning: Doing *can* cause long delays if you are not careful.